# Toggle Class Map On Component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

How can I toggle the "isActive" within my state on my container via the "isSelected" click event within my component?

Please see the "List Accounts" component imported within my container. I'm passing the accounts data via props.

When I iterate through each account I want to check if "isActive" true or false.

I assume this will determine when the class is rendered.

Is it possible to have the "item" within the map function listen to state and update state within my "isSelected" function?

What is the best way to approach this?

Here is my container code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import './index.css'; // styles from

import ProfileHeader from '../../../components/ProfileHeader';
import ListAccounts from '../../../components/ListAccounts';

import { fetchingPageData } from '../../../actions';


class WhosWatching extends Component {
  state = {
    accounts: [
      {
        isActive: false,
        isChild: false,
        name: 'Olivia',
        avatar: '/images/avatars/profile-img-03.png'
      },
      {
        isActive: false,
        isChild: false,
        name: 'Fred',
        avatar: '/images/avatars/profile-img-01.png'
      },
      {
        isActive: false,
        isChild: true,
        name: 'Dirk',
        avatar: '/images/avatars/profile-img-02.png'
      },
    ]
  }

  render() {
    const listAccounts = this.state.accounts;
    return (
      <div className="whos-watching-wrap container">
          <ProfileHeader />
          <h1>Who's Watching?</h1>
          <span>Select an account or add a new profile</span>
          <ListAccounts accounts={listAccounts} />
          <div className="whos-watching-cta">
            <button>Add Profile</button>
          </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
};
```

Here is my component for List Accounts:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import KidsIcon from '../../assets/svg/icons/kids.svg';

import './index.css';

export default class ListAccounts extends Component { 
    isSelected() {
    }

    render() {
        const { accounts } = this.props;
        return (
            <div className="list-accounts-wrap">
                {accounts.map((item, i) => {
                    return <div className="list-accounts-item is-selected" onClick={() => this.isSelected()} key={i}>
                        <img src={item.avatar} />
                        <div className="account-details-wrap">
                            <span className="account-name">{item.name}</span>
                            {item.isChild == true ? <KidsIcon /> : null }
                        </div>
                    </div>
                })}             
            </div>
        )
    }

}
```

Comment: do you want to sync with main state (WhosWatching) when toggle hit?

Comment: @NishantDixit Yes as this data will need to be stored in a local session so I will need to get it from state during the user journey. I assume?

Comment: @Flith check my answer I think It is matching with your requirement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import './index.css'; // styles from

import ProfileHeader from '../../../components/ProfileHeader';
import ListAccounts from '../../../components/ListAccounts';

import { fetchingPageData } from '../../../actions';


class WhosWatching extends Component {
  state = {
    accounts: [
      {
        isActive: false,
        isChild: false,
        name: 'Olivia',
        avatar: '/images/avatars/profile-img-03.png'
      },
      {
        isActive: false,
        isChild: false,
        name: 'Fred',
        avatar: '/images/avatars/profile-img-01.png'
      },
      {
        isActive: false,
        isChild: true,
        name: 'Dirk',
        avatar: '/images/avatars/profile-img-02.png'
      },
    ]
  }
  
   handleSelect(i) {
      let rawAccountsData = this.state.accounts;
      rawAccountsData = rawAccountsData.map((val, index) =>       {
          val.isActive = index == i ? true : false;
          return val;
      });
      this.setState({
          accounts: rawAccountsData
      });
  }

  render() {
    const listAccounts = this.state.accounts;
    return (
      <div className="whos-watching-wrap container">
          <ProfileHeader />
          <h1>Who's Watching?</h1>
          <span>Select an account or add a new profile</span>
          <ListAccounts accounts={listAccounts}  handleSelect = {this.handleSelect.bind(this)} />
          <div className="whos-watching-cta">
            <button>Add Profile</button>
          </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
};
```

```js
import React, {
    Component
} from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import KidsIcon from '../../assets/svg/icons/kids.svg';

import './index.css';

export default class ListAccounts extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            accounts: props.accounts
        }
    }
    componentWillReceiveProps(props, state) {
        if (JSON.stringify(props.accounts) != JSON.stringify(state.accounts))
            this.setState({
                accounts: props.accounts
            });
    }
  
   render() {
        const { accounts,handleSelect } = this.props;
        return (
            <div className="list-accounts-wrap">
                {accounts.map((item, i) => {
                    return <div className="list-accounts-item is-selected" onClick={() => handleSelect(i)} key={i}>
                        <img src={item.avatar} />
                        <div className="account-details-wrap">
                            <span className="account-name">{item.name}</span>
                            {item.isChild == true ? <KidsIcon /> : null }
                        </div>
                    </div>
                })}             
            </div>
        )
    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I think the function handleSelect is missing from the component?

Comment: Oops! `onClick={() => this.handleSelect(i)}` replace with this `onClick={() => handleSelect(i)}`

Comment: handleSelect is not a function - super strange because I see you're passing it via props on the container.

Comment: Yes same here, any other error you are getting in console?  and can you put `console.log(handleSelect)` inside `render(){`

Comment: Resolved it, I didn't see you'd put accounts, handleSelect = this.props; Next error is  JSON.Stringify is not a function

Comment: I updated `componentWillReceiveProps` function check now.

Comment: Thank you man! I'll update the class on the element using classnames package - legendary!

Comment: Quick one, how can I update only the item that is selected? I need to have only one "is-selected" class visible, like a navigation almost within the accounts array? So if I have 3 items and I click the second, only the second item within that array is updated. Then if I am to select item 3, that becomes "true" and item 2 becomes "false"?

Comment: Updated check `handleSelect` function in first snippet.

Comment: Thank you, just one error: "rawAccountsData" is read-only - I updated to this.rawAccountsData = rawAccountsData.map and works fine

Answer (score 0):

Container

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import './index.css'; // styles from

import ProfileHeader from '../../../components/ProfileHeader';
import ListAccounts from '../../../components/ListAccounts';

import { fetchingPageData } from '../../../actions';


class WhosWatching extends Component {
  state = {
    accounts: [
      {
        isActive: false,
        isChild: false,
        name: 'Olivia',
        avatar: '/images/avatars/profile-img-03.png'
      },
      {
        isActive: false,
        isChild: false,
        name: 'Fred',
        avatar: '/images/avatars/profile-img-01.png'
      },
      {
        isActive: false,
        isChild: true,
        name: 'Dirk',
        avatar: '/images/avatars/profile-img-02.png'
      },
    ]
  }

  toggle = (i) => {
    const accounts = [...this.state.accounts]
    accounts[i].isActive = !accounts[i].isActive
    this.setState({ accounts })
  }

  render() {
    const listAccounts = this.state.accounts;
    return (
      <div className="whos-watching-wrap container">
          <ProfileHeader />
          <h1>Who's Watching?</h1>
          <span>Select an account or add a new profile</span>
          <ListAccounts toggle={this.toggle} accounts={listAccounts} />
          <div className="whos-watching-cta">
            <button>Add Profile</button>
          </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
};
```

List Accounts

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import KidsIcon from '../../assets/svg/icons/kids.svg';

import './index.css';

export default class ListAccounts extends Component { 

    state = {
      accounts: []
    }

    componentDidMount(){
      const { accounts } = this.props;
      this.setState({ accounts })
    }

    componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps){
      if(nextProps.accounts){
        this.setState({ accounts })
      }
    }

    isSelected(index) {
      this.props.toggle(index)
    }

    render() {
        const { accounts } = this.state
        return (
            <div className="list-accounts-wrap">
                {accounts.map((item, i) => {
                    return <div className="list-accounts-item is-selected" onClick={() => this.isSelected(i)} key={i}>
                        <img src={item.avatar} />
                        <div className="account-details-wrap">
                            <span className="account-name">{item.name}</span>
                            {item.isChild == true ? <KidsIcon /> : null }
                        </div>
                    </div>
                })}             
            </div>
        )
    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help! I'm getting errors regarding accounts is undefined within the component and within the WhosWatching container "i" is undefined.